# How can we add a file to a user's files.list via the sdk?

Tags: google-drive-api

We are having issues where sometimes a file that a user can access is not returned when the user issues a `files.list`.  This can happen in many ways.  For example, new members of a Google group will not see previously shared files, as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903820/issue-with-google-drive-api-and-group-sharing/19819141#19819141).  Moreover, acording to [Google documentation](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494827?hl=en) there are other limits on sharing which can prevent shared files from appearing in the "Shared with me" view.  Finally, a user can issue a `files.delete` on a file she doesn't own, and the file will disappear from `files.list` but will still exist.

**What can a user do *via the SDK alone* to cause a file which she can access via `files.get` to appear in the list of files retrieved via `files.list`?**  We are using a service account which impersonates users; the user never authenticates to Google via a browser.  A link in an email that the user needs to click won't work for us, unfortunately.  Accessing the file via the Google Drive UI has the desired effect, but the analogous `files.get` call does not.

The Google Calendar API explicitly exposes a `CalendarList` interface where a user can issue an `insert` to add an existing calendar to her list.  The Google Drive SDK seems like a hybrid `Files`/`FilesList` interface with some of the functionality missing (nothing like `FilesList.insert`) and some of the functionality mixed together (issuing a `delete` as a non-owner acts like `FilesList.delete` but issuing it as the owner acts like `Files.delete`).

If we can't manage the user's files list programmatically then it is not useful for our service.  We could ignore the `files.list` call entirely and just start recursively performing `children.list` queries on all shared folders, but this is incredibly expensive (unless someone knows how to issue a single query which returns all the `Files` resources in a folder and not just the IDs of those resources).

Any help would be appreciated.  We've been trying this many different ways and have been frustrated at every turn.  Thanks!

Comment: >> _unless someone knows how to issue a single query which returns all the Files resources in a folder and not just the IDs of those resources_ <<

At least I seem to have an answer for this part.  According to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903820/issue-with-google-drive-api-and-group-sharing/19819141?noredirect=1#comment29865072_19819141), issuing a `files.list` with `q='folderId' in parents` returns **all** the accessible Files resources in the folder, even if these files don't show up in an unqualified `files.list` call.